# How to decode Javascript/jQuery [object Object]

Tags: javascript, jquery, label, alert

I have this HTML:

```
<input class="radio" type="radio" name="which_app" value="" id="whichApp1" required>
<label class="left-narrow" for="whichApp1">Program #1</label><br />
<input class="radio" type="radio" name="which_app" value="" id="whichApp2">
<label class="left-narrow" for="whichApp2">Program #2</label>
```

I have this script:

```
$( 'input[type=radio][name=which_app]' ).change( function() {
  var label = $("label[for='"+$(this).attr('id')+"']");
  alert( label );
}
```

I get this pop-up alert:

[image]

How can I decode the [object Object] to get the label that was clicked on? (there are other reasons for not using `value=""` at this time so I am trying to focus solely on the `label`. Thank you)

Answer (score 5):

Use this

`alert(label.html());`

or

to get the text

`alert(label.text());`

Comment: Can't accept answer for another 10 mins...so I'll accept in the future sometime (stupid SO)

Comment: I can wait 10 mins :)

Comment: Wow! Longest 10 mins ever.

Comment: Is the 10 mins up yet??